# Having trouble getting a view's visibility to accept a value from it's binding

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm

Before I begin I have added the files relevant to my issue in GIST: https://gist.github.com/4468651

As the title says I have a WPF app(implementing MVVM - or as best as I could being a beginner), and the *MainView*'s Visibility property binding does not seem to be pulling the relevant value from it's *ViewModel*.

On startup, there is a binding error being thrown that indicates that it is not finding the *ViewModel* on instantiation(even though it is passed in to the constructor). The error is as follows:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert '<null>' from type '<null>' to 
type 'System.Windows.Visibility' for 'en-US' culture with default conversions; 
consider using Converter property of Binding. 

NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: EnumConverter cannot 
convert from (null).
at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertFromException(Object value)
at System.ComponentModel.EnumConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
CultureInfo culture, Object value)
at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, 
DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)'
```

I tried both adding a *TargetNullValue* and a *NullConverter* to the binding, which did not alleviate the warning or the issue. I have also tried changing directly to a property which supplies a *System.Windows.Visibility* value to using a data trigger which checks a  boolean property and sets the visibility accordingly, this also did not change either the issues or the warning message.

After everything has been loaded, if I bring up the context menu on the *Tray Icon* and click either *Hide Window" or *Show Window*(which should inform the *MainView* it needs to either be hidden or shown) nothing happens.
This is what I'm expecting to happen in the code(only referencing the files relevant to the issue):

The App.xaml.cs file -

```
namespace ordoFile
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            this.Properties["bgStartup"] = false;

            if (e != null && e.Args.Count() > 0)
            {
                if(e.Args[0] == "-bg")
                {
                    this.Properties["bgStartup"] = true;
                }
            }

            Configs configs = new Configs();
            PresetFilters presets = new PresetFilters();
            OrganisationSyncer organisationSyncer = new OrganisationSyncer();
            TrayApp trayApp = new TrayApp(organisationSyncer, configs);
            Logger logger = new Logger();
            BackgroundOrganiser backgroundOrganiser = new BackgroundOrganiser(new DirectoryModel());
            ForegroundOrganiser foregroundOrganiser = new ForegroundOrganiser(new DirectoryModel());

            DependencyFactory.Container.RegisterInstance<Configs>("configs", configs);
            DependencyFactory.Container.RegisterInstance<PresetFilters>("presets", presets);
            DependencyFactory.Container.RegisterInstance<OrganisationSyncer>("organisationSyncer", organisationSyncer);
            DependencyFactory.Container.RegisterInstance<BackgroundOrganiser>("backgroundOrganiser", backgroundOrganiser);
            DependencyFactory.Container.RegisterInstance<ForegroundOrganiser>("foregroundOrganiser", foregroundOrganiser);
            DependencyFactory.Container.RegisterInstance<TrayApp>("trayApp", trayApp);
            DependencyFactory.Container.RegisterInstance<Logger>("logger", logger);

            MainViewModel mainViewModel = new MainViewModel(trayApp, organisationSyncer);
            MainView mainView = new MainView(configs, trayApp, mainViewModel);

            mainView.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

The *mainViewModel* variable is being set in the constructor of the *MainView* instance via *this.DataContext = mainViewModel*

The MainView.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ordoFile.Views.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ordoFile.ViewModels"
        xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:ordoFile.Views"
        Title="ordoFile" 
        Name="MainWindow"
        Height="500" 
        Width="815">

    <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding WindowVisibility}"  />
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>

    <Grid Name="ContentGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <vw:ForegroundOrganiserView Grid.RowSpan="2"/>

        <vw:BackgroundOrganiserView Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The MainViewModel.cs

```
namespace ordoFile.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        TrayApp _trayApp;

        OrganisationSyncer _organisationSyncer;

        Visibility _windowVisibility;

        public MainViewModel(TrayApp trayApp, OrganisationSyncer organisationSyncer)
        {
            _trayApp = trayApp;
            _organisationSyncer = organisationSyncer;
            OnInitialise();
        }

        /// <summary>
                    /// Return visibilty staus of MainView
                    /// </summary>
        public Visibility WindowVisibility
        {
            get { return _windowVisibility; }
            set
            {
                _windowVisibility = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("WindowVisibility");
            }
        }

        void OnInitialise()
        {
            WindowVisibility = _organisationSyncer.WindowVisibilty;

            // Add method to event handler in OrganisationSyncer
            // that will be called when UI visibility is to be updated.
            _organisationSyncer.UpdateWindowVisibility += CheckVisibilityStatus;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set property to visibility value held in OrganisationSyncer
        /// instance.
        /// </summary>
        void CheckVisibilityStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowVisibility = _organisationSyncer.WindowVisibilty;
        }
    }
}
```

All this appears to work fine, the setter is called, and the UI even tries to read it(I checked this by throwing an exception in the getter which was thrown after the update occurs).

I'm at a loss, and would appreciate any input!

p.s. https://www.dropbox.com/s/03z361qyws4jhuo/ordoFile.zip is a link to the project files if anyone wants to tinker with the actual project as I'm sure I haven't explained the issue particularly well.

Uodate (thanks to Backlash): The error I mentioned previously does not appear to be related my problem of the *MainView* visibility not updating correctly.

Comment: Is the binding itself declared in XAML? What does that binding expression look like? Which property on the ViewModel is it bound to?

Comment: Here is the binding in XAML:

<Window.Style>  
    <Style TargetType="Window">  
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding WindowVisibility}"  />  
    </Style>  
</Window.Style>

Comment: post your xaml in the question. No one will bother downloading your stuff from gist or whatever

Comment: I added the code to the question.

Comment: I'm assuming the constructor of your window is setting the viewmodel to the window's datacontext property?

Comment: It is, apologies for not making that clear, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though not having the binding *Mode* set to *TwoWay* was causing my issues.

Answer (score 4):

From stepping through, the error is this line:

```
<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding WaitImageVisibility}" />
```

Your WaitImageVisibility is a string value.  You'll need to either change that to be of type Visibility (by the way, you typically don't use Visibility as a data type on the view model, but it's not a big deal) or you need a converter that converts from string to Visibility.

Comment: Thanks for that!

I've handled the WaitImageVisibilty property correctly with DataTriggers, and it has gotten rid of the error message.

However, if I bring up the context menu in the TrayIcon and click either 'Hide Window' or 'Show Window', they window visibility does not seem to update.

It would appear the error message I was looking at was not related to the issue I had in mind.

Comment: Have you uploaded your changes to dropbox?  if so, i can take a look again and see what's happening.  If I had to guess, I would say the context menu is not getting the proper datacontext of the window where your command lies.  This is a common issue as context menus are separate windows and do not inherit their control's datacontext.

Comment: It should be updated now, thanks!

The TrayApp class I have created, has an instance of the OrganisationSyncer class which has an event handler in it which informs the MainViewModel to update the property the MainView's visibility is bound to. The tray app calls a method in the syncer which raises the event.

Comment: Wow, ok not sure how to fix this issue.  Several things I've found.  First, the OnPropertyChanged for the WindowVisible is passing in the wrong string value.  Most shocking though, your PropertyChanged event on the ViewModel base class is always null.  This means nothing is subscribing to the event.  My guess is something is seriously wrong with the initialization phase of your application.  As long as that PropertyChanged event is null, binding will be essentially useless for any changes or updates.

Comment: After changing the value being passed into property changed the event handler fires correctly, and the value being passed into property seems to be correct from the Debug.Writeline I've added into the getter. However, the UI just does not appear to be updating with the value. I'm wondering if it it's a dependency property precendence issue; however, I don't see the visibility being set anywhere else. Tough one!

Comment: Actually, the binding works correctly once(on startup); after that, I can set a value, OnPropertyChanged will be called, the handler will not be null, but the UI does not check the binding.